# Dojo: for each row in a grid, have a button that when clicked shows more information from the data store

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

This is proving to be surprisingly difficult.

Suppose I have a grid that displays the name and size of files.

Information is loaded from a JSON file into an instance of `dojo/store/Memory` and then key attributes presented in the grid. How would I include a button on each row of the grid, that when clicked, displays more attributes about the file? These attributes are stored in the `dojo/store/memory`.

Right now I have a row like this in the grid:

```
    {name:"More", field:"id", formatter: buttonFormatter, datatype:"string", noresize: true, width: "120px"}
```

And I attempted to pass the ID to a button using the formatter:

```
    var buttonFormatter = function(inValue){
        var newButton = new Button({
            label: "Details",
            onClick: function(inValue){
                alert("More information about " + inValue + "  goes here");
            }
        });
        return newButton;
    }
```

This doesn't work however.

The difficulties, as far as I can tell, are:

1) Associating each specific button with a specific file from the store

2) Giving the onClick javascript access to data from the store

Thanks for your help!
Tristan

Answer (score 0):

You can use dojo-data-type-event attach point to do the operation. The corresponding method in the grid widget instance will show your more attributes in different style like tooltip,append,dialog and etc as you need

Comment: Sorry, I'm too much of a Dojo newbie to understand. I did try to read up on the things you mentioned though.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this might helps you, but have a look at it.

In this example there's an onclick-Event on a button to zoom to the clicked row.

https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/fl_zoomgrid.html

Regards